# In/at/just behind something

Tags: prepositions

If we have to choose between these three (in/at/just), which one is more suitable to use in this sentence below:

She's ____ behind you!

It was a multiple choice by the way, it must have one answer. I've never heard of *just behind* you, but I've heard of right *behind* you. Since **just** can mean *exactly*, is this the possible answer? And I've also never seen prepositions come before *behind*. So, which one do you think is correct?

Comment: _Just_ is the only possible answer, and is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "she's just behind you" means about the same thing as "she's right behind you".

"Just" and "right" can usually be used interchangeably in this sense of "closely". "Your destination is just up ahead."

The words "in" and "at" can't possibly function as prepositions here, since there's no object noun. Sometimes "in" can act as an adverb or combine with a verb to make an idiomatic phrase, but that doesn't likely work here. Possibly with a very specific context "she's in behind you" could mean something, but would be a shortened and somewhat confusing way to say it.